# Reversing Order of Words in a String in C

Tags: c

So i am trying to write a C program that will examine the data presented to standard input and print (to standard output) the words on each line backwards, with each word separated by exactly one space. I don't want to reverse the letters within a word; i just want reversing order of the words. I would like the program to also pay attention to command-line parameters and also have the program handle multiple files filenames. Here is some code that i have come up with and would like to know if i am on the right track if not what might change to get where i need to get:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void rev(char *l, char *r);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[] = "the world will go on forever";
    char *end, *x, *y;
    for(end=buf; *end; end++);
    rev(buf,end-1);
    x = buf-1;
    y = buf;
    while(x++ < end) {
        if(*x == '\0' || *x == ' ') {
           rev(y,x-1);
           y = x+1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    return(0);
}

void rev(char *l,char *r) {
    char t;
    while(l < r) {
        t = *l;
        *l++ = *r;
        *r-- = t;
    }
}
```

**How can i edit my code to where it can take a string from what a user may have typed in and reverse that string and output the results?**

Comment: Why do you think you are not on the right track? Is there something which is not working as it should?

Comment: If there is a problem, you could use a debugger to step through the code line by line, while checking that all variables and pointers looks okay.

Comment: Please only ask questions that can be answered.

Comment: @misha curious as to why you edited the code from "this is a wonderful day we are having" to "the world will go on forever" ?

Comment: The first change you need to make is properly indenting your code.

Comment: How about reverse entire line, then reverse individual words again?

Comment: @user1832605 -- That part was changed by someone else (look at the edit history).  I only changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

At least given the normal lengths of lines, if I were doing this I'd *probably* do it recursively. In pseudo code it would be something like:

```
function reverse_words:
  read a word
  if end of line return
  call reverse_words
  print word that was read
  return
end function
```

Alternatively, read an entire line, then use roughly the procedure above to process it.

With a little care and judicious use of the standard library, this is only barely more complex than the pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like what you have will indeed reverse words. There are alternate ways of doing this, but this probably works just as well. Based on what you are asking I assume that you ultimately want to reverse the words contained in files whose names are passed in on the command line. If this is correct, I would take the logic in your main function out and put it in a separate function called something like reversewords(), and pass your pointer to it. I would then loop through your arguments and handle each, calling your reversewords function as necessary. I see in your question that you also want to reverse lines of input that the user might type. For that I would add extra code after all the command line parsing is done. This would consist of a loop that repeatedly calls gets() and passes that resulting pointer to your reversewords function. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To read input from user, change `char buf[] = "the world will go on forever";` to:

```
char buf[123];
printf("Please enter a bunch of words: ");
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
```

Then code to remove traling newline, which fgets doesn't strip, if any, in case you want only spaces:

```
int endInd = strlen(buf)-1;
if (buf[endInd] == '\n') buf[endInd] = 0;
/* else user typed longer line than sizeof buf, extra chars are left unread */
```

For reference, first google hit for "man fgets": http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/

Note about that, since it is also man page of `gets`. *Never* use `gets`, there is no way to prevent user from giving you buffer overflow.

Alternate answer: or did you mean, read command line args and print them in reverse order? Try this:

```
for (int ind = argc-1; ind >=1; --ind) {
    // use conditional operator to print space after all args except the one printed last
    printf("%s%s", argv[ind], (ind == 1 ? "" : " ") );
}
```